# RPM package requirements in a special order

Tags: require, rpm, yum, specifications

I am facing the problem, that I need to install two other RPM's in a special order before installing myRPM.
In detail in my RPM I install some config files for sudo and ldap. So, I need these packages to be installed first Requires(pre). Although the pre required package sudo has a required file in /usr/bin/.
This file will be installed with the ldap package.
So, I need the ldap package to be installed first, then sudo and at least myRPM.
My spec file has:

`Requires(pre): myldap_rpm sudo`

But yum is not going to install the package because sudo needs ldap first. Yum seems to check the dependencies of the pre-required sudo package before installing myldap_rpm
Is there any chance to resolve this???

Thanks a lot in advance for sharing your ideas and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**requires(pre)** is a [scriptlet dependency](https://rpm.org/user_doc/more_dependencies.html). This means that dependency (eg sudo) is only required to run the %pre script. When your package is installed `sudo` can then safely be uninstalled. This is not what you want here.

Afaik you cannot change the dependencies of other packages. You can tell what your package depends on, and those dependencies will be installed before your package, but you cannot insert a **myldap_rpm** dependency to **sudo**.

Probably you don't need to reinstall **sudo** though, probably it would suffice to run some kind of "reload" or "configuration" step after the installation of **myldap_rpm**.

Comment: Hi Chris,
thanks for your help.
There is no sudo installed at this point. I am working with AIX and it comes without sudo.
I will change the dependencies from Requires(pre) to Requires, but I think this will not solve my problem...

Comment: no, try using another approach as suggested by the end of my answer. Do you really need sudo to be installed after myldap_rpm? Maybe restarting a service or running a configuration script will suffice.